# sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set' in fedora

Tags: fedora, sudo

I have been using Fedora for more than a year. Suddenly, starting today, all commands with `sudo` give the error:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

I also tried to run as super user using `su`, but after providing my password, I got this error:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

My password is 100% correct. Also, when I start, I get a notification:

```
cannot mount appimage please check your fuse setup.
```

My current os version is 38.

Here is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/su`:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 58144 Jan 21 2023 /usr/bin/su*
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 202344 Jun 20 06:00 /usr/bin/sudo*
```

How can I solve this?

I googled but could not solve the problem. I'm not quite sure what I should do, and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like something corrupted your file system

Comment: No matter what the underlying problem is, the first thing you do is boot from a USB drive and make a backup of your data. Is go as far as saying doing anything else in this situation would be dangerous.

Comment: First, make sure all your data is safely backed up. Then, to evaluate the extent of damage, please run `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/su` and copy/paste the output into your original question. There are many possible causes for symptoms like this: the best would be a mistyped command that has changed the permissions, the worst might be a malware/hacker attack.

Comment: Well, after running 'ls -l /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/su' into terminal, got the output 

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  58144 Jan 21  2023 /usr/bin/su*
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 202344 Jun 20 06:00 /usr/bin/sudo*

Comment: Did you recently run `chmod 777` somewhere?

Comment: Boot from a LiveCD, run `chmod`.

Comment: If /etc got changed too your system is probably currently writable by any user for anything. I could imagine that with care that creating or overwriting  a crontab entry to do the adequate chmod on su and sudo would revert them, but such action should only be made for the goal of backup of valuable data. Same crontab would have to fix /etc/sudoers too. As all this requires quite detailed knownledge this is already very difficult to do. The system got too many changes to hope to revert all of them correctly.

Comment: Regular rights on Fedora 38 are : -rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root  58144 21 janv.  2023 /usr/bin/su
---s--x--x. 1 root root 202344 20 juin  02:00 /usr/bin/sudo